# What's wrong with this SQL UPDATE query?

Tags: php, mysql

I wouldn't ask if i wasn't sure that i have 100% no idea why this isn't working, so, in PHP i'm simply trying to update a value in the MySQL database:

The field im updating
 - Name: read 
 - Type: tinyint 
 - Length: 1

Here is the PHP code:

> do_SQL("UPDATE messages SET read=1
>   WHERE id='".$id."'");

The do_SQL function is working for everything else, so it's something wrong with this statement. I have tried putting 1 in '1' and it still didn't work.m
The error is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'read=1 WHERE
>   id='1'' at line 1

**Thanks for reading!**

Comment: +1 for the slew of wrong answers you managed to elicit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`read` Is a keyword in MySQL, so you can't use it without quoting it (with backticks):

```
do_SQL("UPDATE messages SET `read`=1 WHERE id='".$id."'");
```

Comment: Ahhh! I actually searched for some kind of 'Reserved words' list but didn't find anything. Damn i hate SQL and all its annoying quotes and words and stuff... Thanks!

Comment: @Tommo Khorkrak linked to it in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066756/whats-wrong-with-this-sql-update-query/3066769#3066769); it's here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: @Tommo - love SQL, you'll need it.

Answer (score 3):

read is probably a reserved word in MySQL.

Yep it is [MySQL Reserved Words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html)

Next time check that list before creating a column with a name that's likely to be used already by the database system.

Answer (score 1):

If `id` is numeric, try removing the quotes aka:

```
do_SQL("UPDATE messages SET `read` = 1 WHERE id = ".$id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't quote $id. Let PHP do substitution in the string.

```
 do_SQL("UPDATE messages SET read=1 WHERE id=$id.");
```

Comment: @Tommo There's actually no problem with quoting numerics in an SQL statement

Answer (score 0):

There are no escape characters.

```
do_SQL('UPDATE messages SET read=1 WHERE id=\''.$id.'\'');
```

Comment: His string used double-quotes, so he doesn't need them